# How to handle ImageView for different screen sizes without hardcoding?

Tags: android

I've an app that display list of images along with some text in a listview.
It actually fetches those images through web service.

If i use `wrap_content` for `ImageView`, it may stretch and the list will be irregular if the image size varies.

If i hardcode by giving some width and height (in dp), does it affects our multi screen support concept?

Comment: In which you are displaying your image? ListVIew or GridView?

Comment: Assume it as both scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise you to use wrap_content for the ImageView.
You could try setting a fixed height to it and use it full-width.
For the fixed size you have to use dp(Density Independent Pixels) which will result in having the size of this view 'almost' the same on any device. An by almost I mean you won't have the exact same percentage on the screen(for obvious reasons) but Android will scale it appropriately.

Second and most important is to set the **scale_type** property to the ImageView component in the xml file. There are various options but probably **center_crop** would fit your needs the best(I advise you to try out all the rest of them too, so you can understand the difference between, center, centerCrop, centerInside, fitCenter, fitEnd, fitStart, fitXY, matrix - these are all the possible values scale_type can have).

EDIT:
Here is the documentation description for these types:

- **center** Displays the image centered in the view with no scaling.
- **centerCrop** Scales the image such that both the x and y dimensions are greater than or equal to the view, while maintaining the image aspect ratio; crops any part of the image that exceeds the size of the view; centers the image in the view.
- **centerInside** Scales the image to fit inside the view, while maintaining the image aspect ratio. If the image is already smaller than the view, then this is the same as center.
- **fitCenter** Scales the image to fit inside the view, while maintaining the image aspect ratio. At least one axis will exactly match the view, and the result is centered inside the view.
- **fitStart** Same as fitCenter but aligned to the top left of the view.
- **fitEnd** Same as fitCenter but aligned to the bottom right of the view.
- **fitXY** Scales the x and y dimensions to exactly match the view size; does not maintain the image aspect ratio.

Comment: What if, if my Image contains 700 width and 600 and my Imageview as full width and fixed height 200? Doesn't it looks weird by stretching or compressing the image?

Comment: if so, then you have use some BitmapFactory class to decimate the samples. http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/reduce-bitmap-size-using.html

Comment: It is still better to have a fixed size on the ImageView and use a proper scale_type, than having the height depending on the image height because your UI will look very messy. Think about any other app with rich image content(Facebook, Instagram, etc.) Do they keep ImageView sizes based on the image size? No, because images can look great even with a scale type. I recommend you to use it this way and probably have a new activity where you display the photo in full-screen mode :)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to display it in a ListView then it is better to hard-code the dimension. and add [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) you want to the image.

If you want to use GridView then use this property

```
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

the columns are adjusted dynamically according to the density of the screen when using `auto_fit`